# Asking for extended pay at a reduced rate while relocating?

Tags: new-job, united-kingdom, new-hires, government

I will be starting a new job, but on a fixed-term basis (only 6 months). It's 150mi away. I have already accepted their offer. It's a government/defense role and they've been very forthcoming with adjustments (the role was made specifically for me, and therefore everything has been quite flexible) I've requested. I have accommodation sorted. I'd like to ask to claim expenses for:

- petrol costs to cover 150mi of travel
- maybe storage costs while I'm away
- one weeks' pay (more than happy for it to be at a heavily reduced rate) to cover the time it'll take to move
- In total, I guess I'd want something like £300

Is that reasonable,  given the fixed-term appointment? Yes, I've already accepted the offer, and no, I wouldn't even think about rejecting it if they cannot meet me on this. They've been quite generous.

Comment: I don't understand your question title - you want extended pay and not a reduced, because your extra costs. And the probably answer is no - you have accepted it by signing the contract without mentioning your costs. They might be generous, particulary that such company expenses might be handled also generously by the tax authority, but the main point is that this ship is gone.

Comment: That is something that I thought was strange. I haven't actually signed a contract. I have agreed by writing via email---does that constitute full and complete acceptance?  I was expecting a document like "sign here to accept the offer"...

Answer (score 4):

Asking for travel and/or relocation reimbursement is normal, though it’s best negotiated before you sign.  Some companies do a moving stipend, but that’s usually for perm full time employees.  Getting relo would be very unusual for a 6 month contract, but travel is very customary.

Asking to be paid during a move is not; they will absolutely not do it unless you are such a unicorn that they would hand you arbitrary additional bundles of money (signing bonus or similar is how this would be handled).

Comment: Thanks for your words :) I have asked my manager. I am a young guy and have only worked in academia, where remuneration is particularly poor and rights and bonuses are non-existent... Hopefully the manager chalks it down to inexperience and doesn't think it's rude/laughable.